# Levi-Civita Connection in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

I'm trying to work myself through Riemannian geometry and I believe I still don't have a firm grasp on what the Levi-Civita connection actually defines. Specifically, if $\gamma(t)$ is a geodesic this means that $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)} \gamma'(t) = 0$. However if $\gamma(t)$ is just an arbitrary smooth curve, what does this expression look like? If we stick to Euclidian space, supposedly $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)} \gamma'(t) = \gamma''(t)$, or not? I've been trying to come to this conclusion using a local frame and hence writing $\gamma'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i'(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. Per the Levi-Civita connection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ does this mean I can compute

\begin{equation}
    \nabla_{\gamma'(t)} \gamma'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i'(t) \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}} \gamma'(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i'(t) \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\gamma_j'(t)) \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}
\end{equation}

At this point I'm assuming I'm doing something very wrong here but I have no idea what. For one I'm not particularly getting a straightforward expression and secondly, I thought the connections between the basis vectors were supposed to be all zero (since the Christoffel symbols in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are). How can I derive an expression for this correctly?

EDIT: In the book of do Carmo the definition of an affine connection is given as follows. A map $\nabla : \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$ which satisfies the following properties.

- $\nabla_{fX + gY}Z = f\nabla_XZ + g\nabla_YZ$.
- $\nabla_X(Y+Z) = \nabla_XY + \nabla_XZ$.
- $\nabla_X(fY) = f\nabla_XY + X(f)Y$.

Comment: What book are you using for you study? Can you cite the related definitions? I believe the confusion comes from a slight difference between $\nabla_V X$ (when $V$ and $X$ are tangent vector fields defined on some neighborhood) and $\nabla_V \gamma'(t)$ (when $\gamma'(t)$ is a tangent vector field defined only on an integral curve of $V$).

Comment: Most of my info comes from Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo but I have Intro to Riemannian Manifolds by John M. Lee on hand as well. I'm not sure what you mean with the two different definitions, as far as I understand it $\gamma'(t)$ is just seen as a vector field along the curve $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: Since $\dot\gamma$ is a vector field along the curve $\gamma$, it is *not* a vector field on the manifold; and $\nabla$ can, strictly speaking, only act on vector fields on (an open subset of) the manifold. This is usually addressed by defining a "covariant differentiation along a curve $\gamma$" operator.

Comment: In Lee's book there's a chapter _Connections_ with a whole subsection on _Vector Fields Along Curves_. If you include the relevant definitions, you have a better chance at obtaining an answer (and also a good chance at answering it yourself).

Comment: Hint: Your computation is incorrect, the last term is wrong. Remember, $\nabla_()= X(f)Y+ f\nabla_XY$. 
Also, in order to compute $\nabla_{X_i}X_j$ for coordinate vector fields $X_i, X_j$ you should use the fact that $\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$ 
(the standard flat connection). Could you now figure out how to write the correct formula in the RHS of your equation?

Comment: Yea instead of the nabla of basis vectors at the end I guess I would just get a basis vector straight up. Still don't quite see what would have to happen after that